# Show that the curve given by r(t)=<cos4t,t,sin4t> has constant curvature.

Tags: calculus, 3d

How do I prove this? I can use k=mag(T')/mag(r') but the derivations get extremely hairy. I think I'm over complicating it for myself.

Comment: I can't actually crunch the numbers though. How do I go about actually proving it on paper?

Comment: Nevermind I think I got it. K=16/17=0.94. Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Actually, the curve is three-dimensional, with a constantly increasing $y$-coordinate. It is a helix, which can be defined as a curve with constant non-zero curvature and constant non-zero torsion.

Comment: In this case, you can make the calculations simpler if you parameterize by arclength.

Comment: @Rory: Oops! I didn’t see the $t$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yeah you're right.